# Enable anonymous access to report builder in reporting services 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

I have a 2008 reporting services server installed on windows 2003 server. I am trying to allow anonymous access to the report builder folder so that my users do not have to select the remember password option when they login, if they are wanting to use the report builder.

All I have found so far is that I should be able to do this with the IIS manager, but that only seems to work for reporting services 2005. Reporting services 2008 does not show up in the IIS manager, enabling anonymous access seems to be hidden somewhere else.

How do I enable anonymous access to report builder in reporting services 2008?

Comment: You could integrated authentication so it's not anonymous and still doesn't ask for account. The website must be in their local intranet zone

Comment: Sadly that's not going to be possible for our scenario, otherwise it'd be grand.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication methods for Reporting Services in 2008 are all handled by a file called RSReportServer.config. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281309.aspx for details.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for report builder but seems like Report Server 2008 (access to reports stored on Report Server) does not allow any more anonymous.

Here is link for [MSN Blog about RS and Anonymous access](http://blogs.msdn.com/jameswu/archive/2008/07/15/anonymous-access-in-sql-rs-2008.aspx)

Here is  [programmer's side of story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671694/passing-credentials-to-sql-report-server-2008)